# Is the bounty grantor notified when addressed by '@' in comment?

Tags: support, comments, bounties, comment-replies

If there's a question where a *foreign* user set a bounty and it's their only appearance in the *thread*, will they be notified when I post a comment addressed like `@BountyGrantor`?

In picture:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - it doesn't even matter whether they are the bounty grantor. As long as they are active on that question, using `@username` will notify them; they will receive the notification in their inbox.

Comment: When you say, *as long as they are active on that page*, does it mean that if someone edits a post (as the only activity in the *thread*) and that post is then re-edited by someone else (the user is now hidden from *the site*), that user can no longer be notified? [I know I should ask this separately; you've answered my question, thank you for that!]

Comment: Active on the 'site' , not the 'page' - it doesn't matter if someone else re-edits the post :-)

Comment: D'oh, site! :) I forgot there's a clipboard on my system for a while. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: What is meant by 'site' here?

Comment: @Tim, a *thread* (or in other words a question with all its answers, if there are some), just the particular site that SE generates for you.

Comment: @Rory then this is wrong. They need to have participated in the thread for it to work. Other wise, how would [this](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=tim) work?

Comment: @TLama anyone who has performed any action on this is notified. So bounty people will be, as will anyone who has edited - even if they aren't the latest editor.

Comment: @Rory, ah, so then I got your term *site* wrong. As far as I know, you cannot be notified from any *thread* on the site. Only from where you have participated (as Tim says).

Comment: Ah - sure. OK - gotcha now.